# Mercurial error - hg push, abort:error: ''

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am trying to do a simple push using Mercurial however I get the following response within DOS/cmd:

```
hg push
pushing to https://name@repo.website.com/frontend
http authorization required
realm: Mercurial Repository
user: name
password:
searching for changes
abort: error: ''
```

The password is in lowercase and correctly entered - can anyone suggest why this problem is occuring?

I've done the following command:

```
hg push --debug --traceback
```

It goes through a number of files and at the end states the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error ''>
abort: error: ''
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird.. after a few more attempts of doing a `hg push -v --debug --traceback` it worked perfectly fine... no idea why it happened, I am guessing some odd **timeout issues with the remote server**.

Answer (score 0):

some official tips at [17. Diagnose "abort: Error" messages](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Diagnose_.22abort%3a_Error.22_messages)

1. [disable cgitb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgitb.html) in hgweb on the server
2. run with `--debug --traceback` on the client
3. check the error logs on the server

While going through the same issue, **hg server restart** worked for me (I had no permission to hack on server).